# Error when getting information for file /home/ubuntu/upstart-file-bridge.2901.pid

Tags: usb-drive, home-directory

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.10 from a USB (flash stick in Try Ubuntu mode) because my laptop's hard drive is broken. This is the latest problem I found.

[image]

Why is Ubuntu so slow handling files? It takes 30 seconds or so to open Nautilus, and most of the time the screen is dimmed for a few seconds before getting back to normal.

Copying, deleting and transferring between USB takes like years, even deleting Trash is like taking minutes.

Ubuntu cannot read the HOME directory where all my data files stored.

Comment: 'Structure needs cleaning' means you have corrupted your filesystem. Boot from a LiveUSB and run fsck on that disk.

Comment: Hi user535733,

I am running Ubuntu from USB ( my laptop hard drive burnt ).

I typed <fsck> on terminal, no effect

Comment: If your laptop hard drive is burnt, then recovering your HOME directory where all your data files stored is impossible. Sad. Take your burnt hard drive to a professional data recovery company.

Comment: user535733 thanks.
I have no data on hard drive. 
I am running Ubuntu from USB for the past 12 months. 
Now, I have problem accessing directory HOME where my data is stored.

See the attached pic above.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Ubuntu from a USB flash stick, or a USB 2.0 hard disk, then you can't complain that it's slow, or that you have problems. If you mean "USB hard disk" when you say USB, then read further on.

That being said, you can try to fsck (file system check) the "USB" to see if it'll repair your problem...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If that repairs your USB disk, then...

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and check if you have a partition alignment problem.

Comment: Hi heynnema,

I don't even know how to boot to GRUB, I pressed the SHIFT key, no luck.
On the startup menu
- try ubuntu without installing
- install
-
-
- advanced options 

After I click Advance Options, there was nothing in it , except BACK...<

Comment: GRUB is the menu that you normally see when you boot your USB. If you don't see it, trying holding SHIFT or ESC during boot to bring it up. However, if you're trying to boot a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, then you can use `Try Ubuntu` and then start `terminal` and use `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` where X is the number of your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Hi heynnema,

Yes, I am running Ubuntu from 4Gb USB stick without installation.

Comment: Not good. Trying booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD to repair your USB stick, as my previous comment explains. You may have to change "sdaX" to something else, like "sdbX", and still change the X to the correct partition number. You can probably find the correct partition number if you use `lsblk` and look for a partition with a mount point of / or /home. If you see both, fsck both of them.

Comment: Hi heynnema,

Tried sda2, non-existent. 
Tried sda1, came out list of numbers, and asking copy original to backup or backup to originial, I tried both, my Home directory is not back.

Comment: What is "upstart -file-bridge.2901.pid"? this is the source of problem, I think.

Comment: You're not following instructions. Did you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD? Did you do a `lsblk` to find the correct partitions to fsck? I have no idea why it asked to copy anything... what exact command did you use?

Comment: Hi heynnema,

I don't have Live DVD, I run the ubuntu from USB stick. I downloaded the ubuntu iso file, then I used USB installer to install it on my USB stick
Yes, I tried lsblk on terminal, it says something like this:
- loop1
- sr0
- loop0
- sda
   -sda1  3.8G 0 part / cdrom

Comment: I don't know how to help you. Without a Ubuntu DVD/USB, or access via GRUB Advanced Options, I can't fsck the existing stick. You shouldn't have been running full time on a trial OS from a stick. Sorry.

Comment: Hi heynnema, 

Don't worry, and thanks a lot by the way.


And if I may ask you another question.

- Can I install full Ubuntu on external SSD drive ( USB plug )? Will it better than USB flash stick I am running now?
I do not want to replace my fried hard-drive for $50 while I can get decent 1Gb SSD external for $70.

Thanks

Comment: If it's USB 3.0, and you have USB 3.0 ports, then an external USB SSD would be faster... but you probably meant 1TB SSD... and you can't get that for $70. Best to replace your internal HDD.